# How to get results from Array of Objects in Typescript after converting from json string to json object, what is wrong with my coding

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

see my coding below. I am doing a simple extraction of data from array of objects after converting from json string to json object.

```
export class FourColumnResults {

    constructor(private column1: string, private column2: string,
        private column3: string, private column4: string) {

    }

    public get $column1(): string {
        return this.column1;
    }

    public set $column1(value: string) {
        this.column1 = value;
    }


    /** all getter and setter methods */
}


export class ValidationSummary {

    constructor(private column1: string, private column2: string, private column3: string,
        private column4: string, private column5: string, private column6: string,
        private column7: string) {

    }

    public get $column1(): string {
        return this.column1;
    }

    public set $column1(value: string) {
        this.column1 = value;
    }

    /** all getter and setter methods */

}
```

import { FourColumnResults } from "./FourColumnResult";
import { ValidationSummary } from './ValidationSummary';

```
export class MyConverter {

    public convert(jsonString: string): FourColumnResults[] {
        const results: FourColumnResults[] = [];
        const valSummary: ValidationSummary[] = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        console.log("ValSummary object======== ", valSummary); // This is printing correctly

        for(let i = 0; i < valSummary.length; i++) {
            const value: ValidationSummary = valSummary[i];
            console.log("=====>"+value.$column1);
        }

        return results;
    }

}
```

The following is the actual json string, I am getting from a system.

```
[
  {
    "column1": "Data-1",
    "column2": "Data-2",
    "column3": "Data-3",
    "column4": "Data-4",
    "column5": "Data-5",
    "column6": "Data-6",
    "column7": "Data-7"
  },
  {
    "column1": "Data-11",
    "column2": "Data-12",
    "column3": "Data-13",
    "column4": "Data-14",
    "column5": "Data-15",
    "column6": "Data-16",
    "column7": "Data-17"
  },
  {
    "column1": "Data-31",
    "column2": "Data-32",
    "column3": "Data-33",
    "column4": "Data-34",
    "column5": "Data-35",
    "column6": "Data-36",
    "column7": "Data-37"
  }
]
```

Here, the problem is, I am able to parse the above json string to json object of my type `ValidationSummary.ts` with the following coding.

```
const valSummary: ValidationSummary[] = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

But, I am unable to get the result from the following coding.

```
for(let i = 0; i < valSummary.length; i++) {
            const value: ValidationSummary = valSummary[i];
            console.log("=====>"+value.$column1); // Prints Undefined
        }
```

What is wrong with my coding ? Please help me resolve.

Comment: It would be `value.column1` without the `$`

Comment: No, it does not work as per my getter and setter methods

Comment: Your question is actually a good one. Please cleanup and focus on the issue at hand. @Deba

Answer (score 0):

It should be `value.column1` instead of `value.$column1`

```
for(let i = 0; i < valSummary.length; i++) {
    const value: ValidationSummary = valSummary[i];
    console.log("=====>"+value.column1); // Prints the value
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work as per my getter and setter methods, VS Code does not allow me do so.

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE**

Since you are parsing from a string, It will not have original Class properties. Specifying with colon

```
const value: ValidationSummary
```

will just provide type to the data.

**ANSWER**

You must provide an reviver function to the `JSON.parse` function as follows.

Data should have a key to revive the data, so, maintain a key,

```
const s = '{"data":[{"column1":"Data-1","column2":"Data-2","column3":"Data-3","column4":"Data-4","column5":"Data-5","column6":"Data-6","column7":"Data-7"},{"column1":"Data-11","column2":"Data-12","column3":"Data-13","column4":"Data-14","column5":"Data-15","column6":"Data-16","column7":"Data-17"},{"column1":"Data-31","column2":"Data-32","column3":"Data-33","column4":"Data-34","column5":"Data-35","column6":"Data-36","column7":"Data-37"}]}';
```

Your class should have a `from` function that will create object from json data.

```
class ValidationSummary {

    constructor(private column1: string, private column2: string, private column3: string,
        private column4: string, private column5: string, private column6: string,
        private column7: string) {

    }

    static from(json: ValidationSummary) {
        return Object.assign(new ValidationSummary(), json);
    }

    public get $column1(): string {
        return this.column1;
    }

    public set $column1(value: string) {
        this.column1 = value;
    }

    /** all getter and setter methods */

}
```

Finally, the reviver function that will map the class functionality to the data.

```
function reviveData(key: string, value: any) {
    if (key === 'data') {
        return value.map(ValidationSummary.from);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Pass the data and the reviver function

```
data = JSON.parse(s, reviveData).data;
console.log(data[0].$column1);
```

Output

```
"Data-1"
```

[image: Data as objects]

CODE: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=1#

Comment: Let me try your code.

Comment: `return Object.assign(new ValidationSummary(), json);` gives me compilation issue in VS Code as it requires parameters for constructor

Comment: You need to give initial values in the constructor or some dummy values while constructing. @Deba